# Maven: Downloaded jar manually, now how to tell maven to skip it while doing a mvn install

Tags: maven

I have installed the jar manually using `mvn install:install-file` command. Now when I try to do a `mvn compile or a mvn install`, it again tries to fetch that dependency and fails. Now though I already have that locally (installed using the above command). How can I skip this step where in it does not go to that repository to fetch that dependency?

Comment: Have you used the correct `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` during the install? (You don't have to go offline to use manually installed jars)

Comment: Yes! It gives this error: Failed to execute goal on project storm-kafka: Could not resolve dependencies for project storm:storm-kafka:jar:0.9.0-wip16b-scala292: The repository system is offline but the artifact com.twitter:kafka_2.9.2:jar:0.7.0 is not available in the local repository. Though I have the jar present in the correct path.

Comment: could you post the exact command you used?

Comment: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.jar -DgroupId=com.twitter -DartifactId=kafka_2.9.2 -Dversion={0.7.0} -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: and the full error too :) (you could add it the post, so it will be easier to read)

Comment: Thanks Balint. Your comment made me resolve the problem. I placed curly brackets in the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing a `-o` will toggle offline mode in mvn, it will try to resolve everything from the local repo